# "naive datetime is disallowed" when running Bash command using Apache Airflow

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow

It is looking like `sqlAlchemy` might have had a facelift since the time that the  `Airflow` tutorial were written:  it is not accepting a date in the format of `YYYY-DD-MM` that is shown in the tutorial at http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/tutorial.html :

```
 $airflow test tutorial print_date  2017-12-30
[2017-12-29 19:10:40,695] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-12-29 19:10:40,745] {models.py:194} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /git/airflow/home/dags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('apache-airflow==1.10.0.dev0+incubating', 'airflow')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 748, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  ..
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 623, in _init_compiled
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 1074, in process
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy_utc.py", line 31, in process_bind_param
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (exceptions.ValueError) naive datetime is disallowed [SQL: u'SELECT task_instance.try_number AS task_instance_try_number, task_instance.task_id AS task_instance_task_id, task_instance.dag_id AS task_instance_dag_id, task_instance.execution_date AS task_instance_execution_date, task_instance.start_date AS task_instance_start_date, task_instance.end_date AS task_instance_end_date, task_instance.duration AS task_instance_duration, task_instance.state AS task_instance_state, task_instance.max_tries AS task_instance_max_tries, task_instance.hostname AS task_instance_hostname, task_instance.unixname AS task_instance_unixname, task_instance.job_id AS task_instance_job_id, task_instance.pool AS task_instance_pool, task_instance.queue AS task_instance_queue, task_instance.priority_weight AS task_instance_priority_weight, task_instance.operator AS task_instance_operator, task_instance.queued_dttm AS task_instance_queued_dttm, task_instance.pid AS task_instance_pid \nFROM task_instance \nWHERE task_instance.dag_id = ? AND task_instance.task_id = ? AND task_instance.execution_date = ?\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'] [parameters: [{}]]
```

What is the format ***now*** required by `sqlAlchemy` ?  (It appears to be a matter of a missing `timezone` - so I'm also looking into that ..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per python's official documentation, there are two types of datetime objects - aware and naive

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Date and time objects may be categorized as “aware” or “naive” depending on whether or not they include timezone information.

See the example below -

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
date_aware = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
date_naive = datetime.now()
output of 'date_aware.tzinfo' is datetime.timezone.utc    
output of 'date_naive.tzinfo' is None
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#determining-if-an-object-is-aware-or-naive

Answer (score 5):

A format like the following is working:

```
'2017-12-28T12:27:00Z'
```

Where the first portion is the date , then a timestamp after the `T` and then the timezone information.